# How to make it run through my whole range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def isprimelike(n):
    for a in range(2,n-1):
        if pow(a,n,n) == a%n:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

When I check `n` for a given value it just check `2`, then decides if it is true or false and doesn't check the rest of the range. Not sure how to make it check the rest of the range.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using a `return` inside the if-else block. You might want to change the `return` statement by a `print` one indicating if it is a prime number or not.

If you want it to return `True` if all are prime-like or `False` if at least one is not, then do the following:

```
def isprimelike(n):
    for a in range(2,n-1):
        if pow(a,n,n) != a%n:
            print('One element is false')
            return False
    return True
```

The print statement is just to show something, but it's not relevant.

Comment: The problem is when I change it to print it prints for each value in the range.  Is there a way to check through the whole range without printing each value.

Comment: My suggestions of printing was just so you see something as I don't know what you're trying to achieve. Basically, what do you want to happen when the condition is true or false.

Comment: I want it to run through the whole range and if it is true for the whole range tell me its true.  If It runs through the range and is false tell me its false.

Comment: The most important thing to know about this change is that `return` always exits a function and returns the value. What @Ignacio did is moved the returns such that it will either return and exit on a false value, if it finds one, or if it doesn't find one that's false, it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

I would try making a list and allow your for loop to append the results of the range into the list then return the list as a whole so you can have access to all the results.

edit: Complely missed the point of your question. Here's the edit.

```
import sys
def isprimelike(n):
    resultlist = []
    for a in range(2,int(n)-1):
        if pow(a,int(n),int(n)) == a%int(n):
            result.append(True)
        else:
            result.append(False)
    return resultlist

n = sys.argv[1]
resultlist = isprimelike(n)
if True in resultlist:
    if False in resultlist:
        print('List contains both True and False')
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print('List is all True')
        sys.exit(1)
if False in resultlist:
    if True in resultlist:
        print('List contains both True and False')
    else:
        print('List is all False')
```